# suggested algorithms to prevent “image persistence” on an LCD screen

Tags: screensaver, kiosk

I have a Windows application which is displayed on kiosk machines and often runs continuously for weeks. The application is full screen. For reference imagine a screen divided into 2 panels, the left one uses about 30% and the right fills the rest. The left panel is completely static and informational, the right panel has video, image and text slides rotate, animations, etc.

No surprise, the left panel can cause some "image persistence" (screen burn) issues. I am looking for suggested remedies on how to prevent the image persistence issue. I'm only concerned about LCD not CRT.

Check out this "wiper" style solution, give it a few seconds you'll see the line wipe across. http://tinyurl.com/lprt6tr

I like this idea, simple and just overlay it on top, it will work anywhere.

But, my question is how much pixel color change is actually required to avoid the image persistence? Do you need to make sure the pixel changes color at least once every minute, 10 minutes, hour? Does it need to rotate through a range of colors? Does it need to hold a state for a period of time?

Any insight about how often and what kind of color change is needed to actually prevent the problem is what I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you used a URL shortener rather than linking directly to [your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/4w2K3/3/)? There's plenty of room to post full URLs in questions, and most people, including me, prefer to see exactly where a link goes rather than having to use an unshortener. Aside from that, it's a fairly interesting question. Welcome to Stack Exchange.

Comment: unfortunately, yes, the reason is that when I used the jsfiddle link the site required the code block to be included in the post. It really didn't add any information to the post and took up a lot of space, so I went this rout.  I also didn't like the redirect but figured it was pretty harmless.  Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1):

First off, image persistence is not screen burn.  Screen Burn is permanent damage that happens to CRTs and I think Plasmas.

Image persistence occurs on LCDs and can be "repaired" by activating the other pixels in the same area.

I had image persistence on my LCD TV a while back by accidentally leaving my TV on for a long weekend while I was out of town.  I believe a google search said to run a video or random pixel noise generator for as long as the TV was on.  So I ran it for 3 days and it cleared the image persistence.

Personally, I dont think the wipe is enough to prevent image persistence.  The same pixels are going to be activated 99.9999% of the time.  If there is downtime in the evenings, then run a screensaver to activate all the pixels.

Comment: follow up.  So, does this come down to a percentage of time that the pixel is activated in 1 state that causes the image persistence issue, or is does the issue only occur if the pixels is active in 1 state for a particular length of time?  If it is determined by a percentage of time then you are correct, a quick periodic wipe will not suffice.  But, if you need only ensure they change at least once every x time, then the wipe can work.  Any additional info is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: It about being in one state for an extended time